# How to center content in a Bootstrap column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center column's content. Does not look like it works for me. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-1 center-block">
       <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/usth0kd2/2/)

Comment: what are you trying to do, align `span` in center of `.col-xs-1` or align `col-xs-1` in center of  `.row` ?

Comment: I am trying to align any content inside of a column, or better yet in a cell.

Comment: At risk of appearing dumb, center it along which axis?

Answer (score 354, accepted):

Use:

```
<!-- unsupported by HTML5 -->
<div class="col-xs-1" align="center">
```

instead of

```
<div class="col-xs-1 center-block">
```

You can also use bootstrap 3 css:

```
<!-- recommended method -->
<div class="col-xs-1 text-center">
```

Bootstrap 4 now has flex classes that will center the content:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
   <div>some content</div>
</div>
```

Note that by default it will be `x-axis` unless `flex-direction` is `column`

Comment: and change col-xs-1 to col-xs-12 by the way. this might be a typo of yours.

Comment: The <div> align attribute is not supported in HTML5.

Comment: Even if the 'align' attribute was still available it has been considered a bad practice to use it for a long time. Do use the class 'text-center'

Comment: Thanks! This solved it for me as well using the bootstrap 3 method .

Comment: The "text-center" class didn't work for me as I have one button and one loading spinner div. Adding the bootstrap class "d-flex justify-content-around" solved for me.

Comment: @inertia align="center" WORKS AS A CHARM!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 225):

**[Updated Apr 2022]:** Tested and Included the `5.1` version of Bootstrap.

---

I know this question is old. And the question did not mention which version of Bootstrap he was using. So I'll assume the answer to this question is resolved.

If any of you (like me) stumbled upon this question and looking for answers using the current bootstrap 5.0 (2020) and 4.5 (2019) framework, then here's the solution.

### Bootstrap 4.5, 5.0, and 5.1

Use `d-flex justify-content-center` on your column div. This will center everything inside that column.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <!-- Image -->
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to align the text inside the col just use `text-center`

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 text-center">
        <!-- text only -->
    </div>
</div>
```

If you have text and image inside the column, you need to use `d-flex` `justify-content-center` and `text-center`.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
       <!-- for image and text -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div class="col text-center">` worked for me. This answer is better documentation than the offical bootstrap docs.

Comment: I was using multiple button in div.  I wanted them to be in the center of the div.  
<div class="col-md-12  justify-content-center text-center"> did the tricks. thanks.

Comment: Used the text-center class as the “Extra Class Name” in Wordpress.  Saved my day, thank you!

Answer (score 38):

Bootstrap naming conventions carry styles of their own, col-XS-1 refers to a column being 8.33% of the containing element wide. Your text, would most likely expand far beyond the specified width, and couldn't possible be centered within it. If you wanted it to constrain to the div, you could use something like css word-break.

For centering the content within an element large enough to expand beyond the text, you have two options.

Option 1: HTML Center Tag

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1 center-block">
    <center>
      <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Option 2: CSS Text-Align

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1 center-block" style="text-align:center;">
    <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you wanted everything to constrain to the width of the column

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1 center-block" style="text-align:center;word-break:break-all;">
    <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE - Using Bootstrap's text-center class

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1 center-block text-center">
    <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

FlexBox Method

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="flexBox" style="
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;">
    <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/usth0kd2/13/

Comment: Yes, this seems to work if I use lg column instead of xs. But if I have just one column shouldn't that column take as much space as it is available? How am I going to know what column to use given a fact of working in three browsers on three different resolutions?

Comment: Bootstrap Columns utilize responsive percentage based widths, so they should be fairly similar regardless of the resolution. However, if you want them to take 100% of the width when they are isolated, you would have to override the width and min-width properties.

Answer (score 37):

Bootstrap 4/Bootstrap 5, horizontal and vertical align contents using flex box

```
<div class="page-hero d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
 <h1>Some text </h1>
</div>
```

Use bootstrap class [align-items-center](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#align-items) and justify-content-center

[image: Vertically and horizontally center aligned text]

```css
.page-hero {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="page-hero d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <h1>Some text </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 22):

No need to complicate things. With Bootstrap 4, you can simply align items horizontally inside a column using the margin auto class `my-auto`

```
         <div class="col-md-6 my-auto">
           <h3>Lorem ipsum.</h3>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `text-center` instead of `center-block`.

Or use `center-block` on the span element (I did the column wider so you can see the alignment better):

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-10" style="background-color:#123;">
      <span class="center-block" style="width:100px; background-color:#ccc;">abc</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a simple way.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
    <p>My text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The **number 6** controls the **width** of the column.

Answer (score 2):

```
//add this to your css
    .myClass{
          margin 0 auto;
          }

// add the class to the span tag( could add it to the div and not using a span  
// at all
    <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-1 center-block">
       <span class="myClass">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-11 mx-auto

```
 1. col-lg-4 ≥ 1200px (popular 1366, 1600, 1920+)
 2. col-md-6 ≥ 970px (popular 1024, 1200)
 3. col-sm-8 ≥ 768px (popular 800, 768)
 4. col-11 set default smaller devices for gutter (popular 600,480,414,375,360,312)
 5. mx-auto = always block center
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `float:none; margin:auto;` styling to centerize column content.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the above work (like in my case trying to center an input), I used Boostrap 4 offset:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
        <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add as following !

```html
<div  class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12" style="margin: 0.1rem auto; max-width: 99.9%;">
```