# Img tag is not centering for col with mx-auto in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Am trying to add a row with two columns, one is col-7 & another is col-5. In col- am adding a form where as i have problem with col-7 in which am trying to add a png using image tag. I want the image to be be centered vertically and horizontally inside the col-5, am trying to use mx-auto and my-auto but no use.

[image: Final output from figma]

[Here am adding codepen link](https://codepen.io/haribabu-manoharan/pen/XWMjqwa)

```css
.rect {  
  background-color: red;
}

.container {
  border: 5px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-7 mx-auto"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/LC6Wchz/cover-image.png" class="" alt=""></div>
<div class="col-5 rect"></div></div></div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[neramclasses.com](https://www.neramclasses.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use flex in bootstrap since Bootstrap 4.5 and 5.0

```
<div class="col-7 d-flex justify-content-center"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/LC6Wchz/cover-image.png" class="" alt=""></div>
```

try this in your code

Also for reference to another answer: [How to center content in a bootstrap column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163164/how-to-center-content-in-a-bootstrap-column)

Comment: can you also tell me how to vertically center in the col ?? and also why mx-auto not working ?

Comment: as we have used justify-content-center to align horizontally you can use align-content-center to do that vertically