# How can I center the row of these cards? I want that if I have a small screen with only one card per row, that is centered

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I created a simple web page using bootstrap and react.

I have this in a desktop screen:
[image]

While I have this in a mobile screen:

[image]

I have this App.js:

```
import Navbar from "./components/navbar";
import Card from "./components/card";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import marconi from "./images/marconi.webp";
import massolo from "./images/massolo.webp";
// etc etc other pics import



class App extends Component {

    state = {
        cards: [
            {id: 0, nome: "Marconi", prezzo: "300k", immagine:marconi},
            {id: 1, nome: "Massolo", prezzo: "100k", immagine:massolo},
            // etc etc
        ]
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="container">
                <h1> Ciao </h1>
                <hr></hr>
                <div className="row">
                    {this.state.cards.map(card => (
                        <Card
                            key={card.id}
                            nome={card.nome}
                            prezzo={card.prezzo}
                            immagine={card.immagine} />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
            </>
        );
        }
    }

export default App;
```

and this card.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Card extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="col">
            <div className="card text-center" style={{ width: "18rem" , marginTop: 40}}>
            <img src={this.props.immagine} className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
            <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{this.props.nome}</h5>
            <p className="card-text">
                Prezzo = €{this.props.prezzo}
            </p>
            <button className="btn btn-dark">
                Compra
            </button>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Card;
```

I tried several things, but I can't achieve the result I want. I'd like to have the mobile version (with only one card) centered, while in desktop just as is right now.

Rendered HTML:
https://filebin.net/2p9imydkdtdjgj66/renderedHTML.txt

Comment: What were the things you tried? We don't want to have a bunch of answers that start off "Try this:" followed by comments like "I tried that already, but I don't want to use "technique Y" because reasons".

Comment: Remove `width: "18rem"` and check if problem remains

Comment: This sort of question is better presented as just Bootstrap HTML, without the React aspect.

Comment: Have you reviewed the [Bootstrap flex docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/)? It's all made pretty clear there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163164/how-to-center-content-in-a-bootstrap-column align="center" WORKS AS A CHARM!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

When using Bootstrap, you can specify `xxl, xl, lg, md, and sm` breaking points for each of your `col`'s.

So instead of just using `<div class="col"></div>` use `<div class="col-lg-3 col-8"></div>` so that at `min-width: 992px` (`lg` breaking point) the card is in a row of 4. Then below `992px` the cards only span `col-8`.

For the cards to center on mobile, add the `justify-content-center` class to the `.row` so that it centers each card.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-8">
    <div class="card text-center" style={{ width: "18rem" , marginTop: 40}}>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{this.props.nome}</h5>
        <p class="card-text"></p>
        <button class="btn btn-dark">Compra</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-8">
    <div class="card text-center" style={{ width: "18rem" , marginTop: 40}}>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{this.props.nome}</h5>
        <p class="card-text"></p>
        <button class="btn btn-dark">Compra</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-8">
    <div class="card text-center" style={{ width: "18rem" , marginTop: 40}}>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{this.props.nome}</h5>
        <p class="card-text"></p>
        <button class="btn btn-dark">Compra</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-8">
    <div class="card text-center" style={{ width: "18rem" , marginTop: 40}}>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{this.props.nome}</h5>
        <p class="card-text"></p>
        <button class="btn btn-dark">Compra</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This adds needless complexity and size restriction.

Comment: @isherwood how so?

Comment: Columns with numeric designations have fixed size, so it needlessly restricts card size for some cases. It's simply not necessary.

Comment: Of course, they do. That's the point.  I don't see how this is a problem with what the OP was requesting. Four horizontally on desktop, four vertically on mobile with it centered.

Comment: As I explained, the cards are needlessly limited to 66.66666667% of the screen width. I'd want my third of a screen back.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be sure without seeing the rendered output, but I'd bet that either `align-items-center` or `text-center` on the column element would do.

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#align-items
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/text/#text-alignment

Comment: nop. I tried <div className="col text-center" > and <div className="col align-items-center" >  but don't work :/

Comment: Please post rendered HTML and the Bootstrap library in a demo using the editor.

Comment: I posted the rendererd html

Comment: It should be in your question, not on another website. It should also be simplified as far as possible while still demonstrating the problem. I asked for the HTML from the JSX you showed, not your entire document. See [ask].